# ImageView slow when setImageResource

Tags: android

since ShowCaseView development is discontinued, i chose for another way to make the First Tour in my Application, the way is:

i took 7 screen shots from my Galaxy G4 for each screen and made some text in it and display it in a imageView in the first run.

But when i change the image (the user click in a next tip button), it take ages to change and buggy the app, in the tablet(10.1) it work well(i dont know why since the tablet has low processor than the g4)

the images are in a good quality(HD), size is 720:1280, if i change the size to something like 500x600 or smaller, it change faster, but in the tablet the image looks horrible ugly

im using this to change;

```
btnNextTip.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                tipImages.setImageResource(bImage);
            }
        });
```

is there any way to do this? or another good library to do a first tour? or change the images but it not look VGA screenshots ?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good approach would be to seperate your Image Resources so that one with Higher Quality are used for Tablet and one with Lower resolution for your Phones.

You App can detect the screen size of the Device that your App is installed on and based on that, it will choose which image resolution to display.

Check here for details:
[Supporting Multiple Screen sizes - Android Developer](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Answer (score 3):

setImageResource() method is bit slow because it does decoding on UI thread, We can solve this problem using worker thread or AsyncTaks, but a simple and ready made solution is available for that. Which is Glide library. You just need to add it's dependency to your gradle file as:

```
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
```

and then set drawable image using it's id as:

```
Glide.with(context).load(bImage).into(tipImages);
```

Also may be other image libraries like Picasso provide this option.

(You can use the latest version of Glide library instead of 3.7.0)